# How to locate WPF xaml files to display dialog components in CS-Script?

Tags: wpf, xaml, cs-script

When I try to display a WPF dialog (summarydialog) in my CS-Script script.   I get an error that it cannot locate the xaml files.  It's searching here in the Initializecomponent function.

System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/CLTD;component/view/summarydialog.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

summarydialog.xaml  is compiled as "page".

Using dotPeek I see  summarydialog.baml (binary version of xaml)  located in the CLTD.g.resources/View folder.

How can I tell CS-Script how to locate xaml files?  Or perhaps someone knows how to display WPF XAML dialog windows from a CS-Script.

If it's simply the file extension, how does the executable work?  Isn't it using the same DLL assembly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the XAML resource. Since it's already compiled, you can just add a reference to the assembly and then create a new instance of the control like normal.

I created a test .NET 5.0 WPF application to test this and built the project.

Here's the cs-script I wrote.

```cs
//css_ng csc
//css_winapp
//css_ref WindowsBase
//css_ref PresentationCore
//css_ref PresentationFramework
//css_ref C:\projects\TestWpfApp\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\TestWpfApp.dll

using System;
using TestWpfApp;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Then, here's the cli command I ran to run the script:

```
csws.exe new_script.cs
```

[image]